# Problems with MySQL on Linux and 100% CPU load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, htop

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.
Why meanwhile I am deleting this package, the system is starting the relative service?

I need MySQL on this server. How correctly I should execute its installation procedure?

```
root@myhost:~# apt remove mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 112 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 46943 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2021-01-27T16:04:12.673791Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011065] [Server] Unable to determine if daemon is running: No such file or directory (rc=0).
2021-01-27T16:04:12.681639Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Wed 2021-01-27 16:04:16 UTC; 93ms ago
    Process: 2128 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2136 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
   Main PID: 2136 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"

Jan 27 16:04:16 myhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jan 27 16:04:16 myhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jan 27 16:04:16 myhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jan 27 16:04:16 myhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jan 27 16:04:16 myhost systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 27 16:04:16 myhost systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: If you need MySQL, why do you try to remove it?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Please [edit] your post and state which is your goal, what are the steps you followed, what you expected and what you had instead. It will be easier to understand and help.  Feel you free to rollback or integrate my modifications.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille because it was overloading my server CPU to 100% and there was definitely something wrong with it

Comment: Probably you need to shut down the deamon (service) before you disinstall it. Some times It is possible to disinstall a package without stopping the server. Then at the next boot it will not start again. But why to wait the next boot? Moreover, if you want a clean install of a package use `--purge` when you disinstall it. Read always `man apt` to have info. BTW is the server in use by some process you know?

Comment: @Hastur thanks you. But still.. what is the cause of this problem ?

Comment: You're welcome. Somehow already answered... `:-)`. Is the server used by some process? I suppose yes because you stated 100% CPU. For this reason it may be useful to shut down a service before uninstall it... It is difficult to say why, it can be because of child processes using it, child process waiting the end of other childrens....

Comment: Ad nauseam: `2 not fully installed or removed.`  You probably have a previously broken installation. Try `apt-get -f install` and related commands... (Search for other questions about broken packages...e.g. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/462751/196535)). Good Luck.

Comment: /var/log/mysql/error.log  may contain interesting information.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille https://pastebin.com/RWhkLwTp

I really can't get it at all... :(

Comment: mysqld seems to die immediately, and 10 seconds later systemd restarts it.  Can you add the output of "ldd /usr/sbin/mysqld" and also see what you get when you try to run mysqld from the commandline ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille https://pastebin.com/uA3ayAzr
Here is the output

Comment: With commandline, I didn't mean "systemctl restart mysql", but just "/usr/sbin/mysqld".  Right now it seems as if your system runs out of memory the minute mysql is started.  Did you make any changes to the standard configuration?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille No, I didn't. Anyway, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The problem was with my RAM quantity. Which was 512 MB.

There were no clear requirements, and those logs weren't showing this up in an easy way.

Anyway. I enabled swap partition on my server. And now everything runs perfectly. Thank you SO <3

Comment: 512Mb?  Were you ashamed of divulging this information?  BTW, when a database needs swapping, you'll very soon run into high CPU again.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I'm just a poor CS student (from even more poorer country) 
VDS hosting isin't that cheap these days. I got what I got..

p.s. yeah.. i can only imagine..

Comment: I'm sorry.  Should have kept my mouth shut.  But I would configure MySQL so that it doesn't exceed available memory - unless it's never going to be used regularly.  OTOH, there are a couple of big names offering free cloud systems with a 1Gb system.